# Call a Webservice from Visual Studio with an existing XML-file/string

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, call, webservices-client

How can I call an existing webservice (somewhere) from Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (C#) with only a valid xml-string/file?

I receive these xml-files from another system and this system can not call directly this webservice. These xml-files are 100% ok, but I want to know how to make the code.

Do I need to make the proxy classes?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the WSDL file that describes the service? You can generate code using the [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) command line tool, and then add the generated files to your project. Visual Studio's web service discovering mechanism is geared towards adding services from known URLS.

Comment: In VS, where the discovery dialog asks for a URL you can also put a file path to the WSDL and this will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Webrequest-method and fill the soap-message with the received xml-string and 
send it to the webservice.

So my question can be closed.